# How can I have an access to a TextBox in a UiElementCollection?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox, uielementcollection

My question seems to be simple and I hope it is.
I have a dynamic collection of `TextBox` in a `UiElementCollection`.
The `TextBox` are children of a `StackPanel`.

My goal is simple :
Create a new `TextBox` with the `Text` of for example `UiElementCollection[1]`.

```
TextBox myTextBox = new TextBox();                        // New TextBox
UiElementCollection myCollection = myStackPanel.Children; // New Collection

// If I call this :
myCollection[8] = myTextBox; 
// Error when I call my method
// --> System.ArgumentException

// If I call this  :
myTextBox = myCollection[8];
// Error in my code
// --> Cannot convert.. UiElement to Controls.TextBox

string myString = myTextBox.Text;
```

Any one can help me to handle this please ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You have to cast it first, there is no implicit conversion:

```
myTextBox = (TextBox)myCollection[8];
```

Of course, it is likely a good idea to *check* if that was a `TextBox` first using `is`, or do a null check and `as`.

Also, the standard note for WPF applies here, in general you should be accessing such data through bindings, not direct UI manipulation.